# What do the '4' and 'b' signify in a layer of a crystal called a '4Hb' crystal or material?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, topology, crystals, topological-phase

From Phys.org:

Study gathers evidence of topological superconductivity in the transition metal 4Hb-TaS2

Which, in turn, references:

Abhay Kumar Nayak et al, Evidence of topological boundary modes with topological nodal-point superconductivity, Nature Physics (2021). DOI: 10.1038/s41567-021-01376-z

Journal information: Nature Physics

H is hexagonal, correct?  And T is trigonal?  Q is tetragonal?

But what do the numbers signify?  Number of layers stacked perfectly of that type?

And what does the second, lowercase letter mean?  A slightly different, 'beta' type of hexagonal crystal?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Crystal-structure-of-4Hb-TaS2-The-unit-cell-consists-of-four-layers-of-Ta-atoms-with_fig1_350005716 has pretty pictures. Maybe I'll have time to dig deeper into the terminology (although the 4 seems to be the repeat distance in stacking, and H for hexagonal seems likely. Perhaps 'b' is one of several varieties of stacking?).

Answer (score 1):

The 4Hb notation goes back a long way, and how specific to layered transition metal dichalcogenides it is I'm not sure. A [paper in J. Phys. Chem. Solids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022369773800344?via%3Dihub) by Di Salvo et al. at Bell Labs from 1973 lays out the schema:

> Each layer of TaS2 is 3 atoms thick, the top
> and bottom sheet of atoms are sulfur and the
> middle sheet is tantalum. The atomic sheets
> are all regularly close packed, so the usual
> notation for hexagonally packed atoms may
> be used. An individual layer may have AbC or
> AbA stacking. (The capital letters refer to the
> sulfur and the lower case to the tantalum
> atoms.) In the AbC layers the tantalum atoms
> are at the center of sulfur octahedra, while in
> the AbA layers they are at the center of a
> trigonal prism of sulfur. The crystal structure
> is then obtained by stacking these octahedral
> and/or trigonal layers in an orderly way on
> top of one another. The polytypes of TaS2
> have various designations - 1T, AbC; 2H,
> AbA-CbC; 3R, AbA-BcB-CaC; 4Hb, AbA-CbA-CbC-AbC; where the stacking sequence
> is given for a unit cell.

They go on:

> The labels for the various polymorphs are
> easily generated: the number indicates the
> number of layers per unit crystallographic
> cell, the letter the unit cell symmetry (T--
> trigonal, H = hexagonal, R = rhombohedral),
> and finally a third lower case letter is used
> when the first two do not uniquely identify
> the polytype.

So, "4" means a four layer repeat. "H" is Hexagonal. "b" is one specific stacking in the 4H family.